# MongoDB index performance: multiple indexes vs. single composite index?

Tags: mongodb, performance

Given a simple `products` schema that has four fields, `merchantId`, `gender`, `category` and `color`, would performance be better to have four separate indexes (one for each field) or to have one single composite index which uses all four fields?

The use case is that periodically I want to run aggregations that use any  combination of the above four fields as the `$group._id`.